# Difference of closed sets under closed map

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous, closed map between topological spaces.  Let $E,F$ be closed subsets of $X$.  Is $f(E-F)$ the difference of closed subsets of $Y$?

I am interested in this because, as applied to the Zariski topology, a positive answer would imply a positive answer to the question [Image of quasiprojective variety under closed map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277140/image-of-quasiprojective-variety-under-closed-map).

(Note also that for a general continuous map $g$, it is not necessarily true that $g(E-F)=g(E)-g(F)$, which would be the obvious first thing to try).

**UPDATE:** A counter-example has been found - see [Image of quasiprojective variety under closed map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277140/image-of-quasiprojective-variety-under-closed-map).